# How to create a service that forces a port to Listen state in order to test a PowerShell function?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, testing

A PowerShell script has been created to create a service. One of the snippets tests whether a service is running and a port that is associate to the service *listens*:

```
if (($serviceStatus.Status -eq "running") -and (Get-StatePort)) {
    Write-Host "$packageName service has been started"
    return
} else {
    Write-Host "$packageName service cannot be started. Attempt $i to start the service."
}
```

**testService.bat**

```
ping localhost
```

**Create service**

`nssm install installServiceTest "C:\testService.bat"` creates a service:

```
PS C:\> Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Service -Filter "Name='installServiceTest'"

ExitCode  : 0
Name      : installServiceTest
ProcessId : 5288
StartMode : Auto
State     : Running
Status    : OK
```

The service runs, but the next step is to extend the script to allocate a port and forces it to a Listen State.

E.g. port 9999 should Listen once the script has been started.

```
PS C:\> Get-NetTCPConnection -State Listen | Where-Object {$_.LocalAddress -match "::|0.0.0.0" -and $_.LocalPort -eq "9999"}
PS C:\>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add the following:

```
$port=9999
$IPendpoint = new-object System.Net.IPEndPoint ([system.net.ipaddress]::any, $port)
$listener = new-object System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener $IPendpoint
$listener.start()
$client = $listener.AcceptTcpClient()
```

Then on another window:

```
Get-NetTCPConnection -State Listen | Where-Object {$_.LocalAddress -match "::|0.0.0.0" -and $_.LocalPort -eq "9999"}

LocalAddress                        LocalPort RemoteAddress                       RemotePort State       AppliedSetting
------------                        --------- -------------                       ---------- -----       --------------
0.0.0.0                             9999      0.0.0.0                             0          Listen
```

More about this [here](http://learn-powershell.net/2014/02/22/building-a-tcp-server-using-powershell/)